# Run time error 5:invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vb6

Here is the code which I have written in vb6...it is showing error in text1.setfocus

```
Private Sub Text1_Lostfocus()
    s1 = Text1.Text
    flag = 0
    If Text1.Text = "" Then
        flag = 1
    End If
    For i = 1 To Len(s1)
        l = Mid(s1, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(l) = True Then
            flag = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If flag = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Enter valid input"
        Text1.ForeColor = vbRed
        Text1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please provide a [repro].

Comment: Why is the lost focus event firing?  If it's because the text1 control has been disabled (eg `Text1.Enabled = False`), or if the textbox parent container (if any) has been disabled, then that would cause an invalid procedure call on the Text1.SetFocus method.

Comment: What error is shown? Not enough information is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Do not have this code in LostFocus, instead try to have it in the Validate event, there would be an cancel parameter to the event, if you set Cancel = True (means the cursor will not exit the control) you need not do setfocus

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Text1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If IsNumeric(Text1.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox "Enter valid input"
        Text1.ForeColor = vbRed
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or, be a little cheesier about it and just precede the SetFocus statement with an "On Error Resume Next" statement (hopefully with a following "On Error Go To 0").  Étienne's way is better...

Comment: Since it seems strange that the Textbox would have focus if it's hidden or disabled, handling the error with an `On Error` statement is probably better!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have an empty string and you are trying to work with it in your loop you can get an invalid procedure call. Skip over it altogether and
don't run the loop if the text is empty.

```vb
Private Sub Text1_Lostfocus()
    s1 = Text1.Text
    flag = 0
    If Text1.Text = "" Then
        flag = 1
    Else
        For i = 1 To Len(s1)
            l = Mid(s1, i, 1)
            If IsNumeric(l) = True Then
                flag = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    If flag = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Enter valid input"
        Text1.ForeColor = vbRed
        Text1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this error in a large project.  In our case, the cause turned out to be set focus on an object which at the time was not visible.